# How to get description from the response code returned by BillingClient in Android?

Tags: android, android-billing

I am using the new Play Billing Library 1.0 in my Android app. After the purchase process is complete, in `onPurchasesUpdated`, I get the `responseCode` as an `int` from Google Play. How do I programmatically get the description for this `responseCode` in my app?

Is there is a better way than using a switch case and manually typing the descriptions? Is there was a method that returns the description?

Comment: You'll need to write a custom class with static description of responseCode.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I programmatically get the description for this responseCode in
>   my app?

responseCode is ***BillingClient.BillingResponse***

- BILLING_UNAVAILABLE = 3
- DEVELOPER_ERROR = 5
- ERROR = 6
- OK = 0
- ....

[see more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponse.html)

Comment: I know that. I was asking if there was a better way than using a switch case and manually typing the descriptions. If there was a method that would return the description.